# Setting up Mercurial automated deployments from my box (Windows) to my webserver (Linux)

Tags: svn, deployment, mercurial, dvcs

I'm interested in getting set up with hg/Mercurial on my webserver (Site5). Right now I use SVN through Springloops, and it couldn't be easier. I commit code to Springloops through TortoiseSVN, and it automatically deploys to my Site5 servers via FTP.

This is the exact functionality I am looking for with hg. My client box is Windows 7 (cannot be Ubuntu since I run proprietary biomechanics software that only runs on Windows - and not WINE) and I want to push a repository and then to the Site5 webserver.

I looked into Bitbucket, but it does not do deployments.

Is there a way to set it up so I push to a repository on Site5 which is copied to the webserver directory? (therefore eliminating the middleman)

I'm trying to move to DVCS and away from SVN for future-proofing even though I am the sole contributor to the projects I'm working on, but I'm having trouble finding tutorials/products/services that "just work" like SVN does with Springloops. (To be fair, git works with Springloops in much the same manner - I'm just interested in finding a free repository that allows for more than 1 active project and a repo that supports hg.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Mercurial Hooks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook). Particularly, changegroup hooks in your case.

You can set up a hook on your server to copy the files to the webserver directory.

Without more informations about your server (Site5), it's difficult to be more precise.

Comment: I'll accept this answer though I didn't have much luck with it.